# Rspec undefined method 'to'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

So I have an undefined method error which is for the  Rspec method 'to'.  I have a spec with the following code

```
  it "sends an email to users who have favorited the post" do
    @user.favorites.where(post: @post).create

    allow ( FavoriteMailer )
      .to receive(:new_comment)
      .with(@user, @post, @comment)
      .and_return( double(deliver: true))
```

When I run the spec I get the following error:

```
1) Comment after_create with users permission sends an email to users who have favorited the post
 Failure/Error: allow ( FavoriteMailer )
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `to' for FavoriteMailer:Class
 # ./spec/models/comment_spec.rb:18:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just remove space before first bracket, so you could write:

```
 allow( FavoriteMailer )
```

but better it looks like:

```
 allow(FavoriteMailer)
```

in your case: `allow (FavoriteMailer).to ..` is interpreted as: `allow((FavoriteMailer).to ..)`